# Checkbox form validation in Firefox

Tags: firefox, forms, checkbox

Form validation for check boxes only seems to be working in IE....? Anyone have a sample of it working in FF?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using <ASP:Checkbox/> or <input type="checkbox" runat="sever" .../> ?

Comment: input type....(pure html for form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var isChecked = document.forms['myform'].elements['mycheckbox'].checked;
if (!isChecked) {
  alert('You must agree');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Um...Your question isn't exactly a clear one.

If it's form validation as in checking then shouldn't you be doing this server side? Which would be browser independent.

If you are doing any form validation with Javascript and then passing it to the server you must always check it server side as well...a simple http request could easily mess up a system that doesn't.

If you have a Javascript library that you are using to validate forms then it might be an idea to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain your element (checkbox) value, you can use something a bit more cross browser compatible....

var CheckBox = document.all ? document.all["checkbox"] : document.getElementById("checkbox");
var isChecked = CheckBox.checked;

Comment: Please - never ever use document.all unless you are writing a method to specifically overcome IE's buggy document.getElementById() method.

Comment: Well microsoft support and use this notation for cross browser compatibility, if you think its a problem, take it up with them.